Absolute and potential vorticity conservation
The source processes for (vertical) vorticity in the baroclinic vorticity equation are the stretching, tilting and solenoidal terms. I understand that all of these terms go to zero in a barotropic setup; so what processes actually convert one form of vorticity to another (ex planetary to relative if you displace a parcel, such that absolute vorticity is conserved) in the barotropic case? How are these different from the baroclinic source processes?
The next part of my doubt is potential vorticity —> what extra ‘factor’ does it physically account for that absolute vorticity does not that allows it to be conserved even in the baroclinic case? What does it physically mean?

I think this should be split into two separate questions (the PV question is a different one?)
